# Apache 2.4 | Problem with @ in my UNIQUE_ID : ZJq5XcCoAcgAAGIGQ@gAAAAC

Tags: php, apache2.4, nonce

Recently I'm trying to match the security standards. So I'm using CSP lvl 3 which requires the use of a nonce.

It works very well except sometimes in the UNIQUE_ID generated I have an @. As soon as it is present my resources are no longer loaded.

In my Apache file: its set like this script-src 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e'

Php side:

$mynonce=$_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID'];

I really did it with all my knowledge base and then searched the web to see if there were any discussions on the subject and I couldn't find any. [Screen to show that the result is good on both sides, server and client. As soon as an @ appears, the policy no longer works. I have to refresh. my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuBM2.png)

I'm on Apache 2.4 and Debian. I find nothing about it.

Edit: For the resource to load, the unique id must be the same in the header as the server-side id. This is the case. It works well but when there is an @ it no longer considers the unique id of the header == that of the server whereas when read they are identical even with the @. So I'm trying to find out how to have a unique 64-bit id in order to eliminate special characters. I think its the solution.

Comment: it works well 99% of the time. But sometimes an @ appears in the unique id, check the image. And when it's there it doesn't work any more, so I have to refresh the page. It's as if the @ wasn't welcome in the key. @ÁlvaroGonzález I edited my text.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález
In the broswer console: 
Content Security Policy: Les paramètres de la page ont empêché le chargement d’une ressource à https://img.*****.com/js/wikidp3.js (« script-src »).

Comment: Small update: 
The source list for the Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''nonce-ZJwb0MCoAcgAAD5V@-IAAAAE''. It will be ignored.